# Is Ecuador visa-free for Nigerians?

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, nigerian-citizens, ecuador

As the subject states, is Ecuador visa-free for Nigerians at this time?

Comment: Did you check the website of the Ecuadorian embassy in Nigeria? Of the Ecuadorian government's visa site? Or Wikipedia's list of visa requirements for Nigerians?

Answer (score 2):

As per the below reference, no it is not a visa free nor on arrival. 
https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=ng&fl=&s=yes

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the website you link is no "reference" you would be able to cite to an airline employee or immigration official. It is a site sponsored by a consultancy which helps rich people acquire additional citizenships, and they have no particular incentive to maintain it. They claim the data is derived from "public sources," so it would be better to link to those public sources.